# What's the difference between 都 and 对?

Tags: word-choice, difference

I've seen these two sentences on Duolingo:

> 我们都是老师。 (We are all teachers.)
>
> 他们对不是美国人。 (None of them are American.) (Not sure if this was exactly the one that I was supposed to translate...)

But the second one can also be written as

> 他们都不是美国人。

So what's the difference between 都 and 对?

Comment: I think you meant 才， but you confused it with 材， and then made a typo, used the simplified character for對 instead

Comment: 他们对不是美国人. simply not a valid sentence. with unknown meaning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've been learning Chinese for 12 years and I don't think I've seen 对 used in that way before. However, the「对不是」 could be a typo of 「绝对不是」 "certainly not". So, maybe it could be this:

> 我们都不是美国人。
>   None of us are American.
>
> 我们绝对不是美国人。
>   We're definitely not American.

Hope that helps.

Comment: "Definitely" is fine, but I think "absolutely" is a slightly better translation of “绝对.”

Comment: @Marko that would certainly be appropriate in many situations, but of course without a context, it's hard to say

Answer (score 1):

'他们对不是美国人。 '  is a wrong sentence.
the right one is '他们都不是美国人。'